# How to allocate redis-sentinel pods on different nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, redis, redis-sentinel

I'm running the redis chart (https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/redis/15.7.0) as a dependency of a custom chart. I enabled sentinel, then the pods are running two containers (redis and sentinel).
I'm using the default values for the chart and I defined 4 replicas. The cluster have 10 nodes and I notice that three redis-sentinel's pods run on a single node and only one runs in another node:

```
myapp-redis-node-0    2/2    Running    8d     ip    k8s-appname-ctw9v
myapp-redis-node-1    2/2    Running    34d    ip    k8s-appname-ctw9v
myapp-redis-node-2    2/2    Running    34d    ip    k8s-appname-ctw9v
myapp-redis-node-3    2/2    Running    34d    ip    k8s-appname-crm3k
```

This is the affinity section for the pod's:

```
spec:
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app.kubernetes.io/component: node
              app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
              app.kubernetes.io/name: redis
          namespaces:
          - test
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
        weight: 1
```

How I can do to have each pod on diferent nodes?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the values.yaml file you're using here in order to try to replicate this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers. Finally I solved it with:

```
spec:
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchLabels:
            app.kubernetes.io/component: node
            app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
            app.kubernetes.io/name: redis
        namespaces:
        - test
        topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

BTW, this is generated automatically by the chart by setting in values for master and replicas (I'm using v15.7.0):

```
podAntiAffinityPreset: hard
```

Comment: Yes @Martin, that is one of the solution but you might wonder why no one recommended it. The reason is it has some downsides. If the required no. of `pods` are more than the no. of nodes in the cluster, the `pod` will go into `Pending` state and wait for `cluster-autoscaler` to create a new node - which is done one at a time - can be time consuming if too many pods.
Also, for some this might add unnecessary cost because you have extra nodes running just to support this `hard` requirement & there might be nodes with enough free resources to host the extra `pods` in case of `soft` requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `podAntiAffinity` section of the pod template to add a certain k/v pair. This will ensure that for a node, if a pod with that k/v pair already exists, the schedular will attempt to schedule the pod on another node that doesn't have a pod with that k/v pair. I say attempt, because anti-affinity rules are `soft` rules and if there are no nodes available, a pod will be scheduled on a node that might possibly violate the anti-affinity. Details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#types-of-inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity).

Try patching the template as:

```
spec:
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 100
        podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: <ADD_LABEL_HERE>
              operator: In
              values:
              - <ADD_VALUE_HERE>
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that `matchLabels` is the problem in the OP's configuration?

Comment: Probably, yes. They appear strange to me.

Comment: Well, they are accepted `selector` as well. Found something here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#resources-that-support-set-based-requirements

And the configuration posted by the OP works for me. 6 replica's on a 6 node cluster - all pods on a different node.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if it is the type of the cluster that is an issue. For instance, if they are ec2 instances, the node configuration can effect the scheduling policy of k8s.

Answer (score 0):

There's a dedicated configuration to ensure what you want, called: `PodDisruptionBudget`.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/

It ensures that your pods are distributed among nodes for high availability and will help you if you want to replace a node etc.